# "Google Auth Library: Node.js" expects localhost:3000 as redirect uri

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-authentication

I am using `@google-cloud/local-auth` to auth an application on a node back end. I have set up a `OAuth 2.0 Client IDs` with the type of `Web application` on the google console and pointed the `Authorized redirect URIs` to `http://localhost:3001` because that is the port I am using for dev, however I can see that the source code for `@google-cloud/local-auth/build/src/index.js:56:15` clearly expects `3000`

```
if (redirectUri.length === 0 ||
  parts.port !== '3000' ||
  parts.hostname !== 'localhost' ||
  parts.pathname !== '/oauth2callback') {
  throw new Error(invalidRedirectUri);
}
```

Why would this be hardcoded, what happens when you use a diferent port?

I am adding my code for context

```
import gsc from '@googleapis/searchconsole'
import { authenticate } from '@google-cloud/local-auth'
import { resolve } from 'path'

export default async () => {
  // Obtain user credentials to use for the request
  const auth = await authenticate({
    keyfilePath: resolve('requests/client_secret.json'),
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly'
    ]
  })

  google.options({ auth })

  const res = await gsc.sites.list({})

  console.log(res.data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This library is meant to demonstrate authentication for **sample** purposes; it should be treated as a starting point for building an application and **is not** a general-purpose solution. [Read it here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-local-auth)

That port number is expected since this library is for demonstration purposes, if you are developing a production-ready application, you need to use something like https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs